# biblatex footcite author and title

Tags: biblatex

I need a footcite that returns:

1. Author: last name all capitalized-first and medium name only the first letter capitalized. In this order: last name comma space first name dot.
2. Title: First letter of first word capitalized. All others words lower case.

Here is my tex file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid, natbib=true, isbn=false]{biblatex}

\bibliography{juridico.bib}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\renewcommand*{\mkibid}{\emph}
\date{}
\author{José Eduardo da Costa\\Juiz de Direito(SP)\\Doutor em direito pela Pontifícia Universidade Católica de São Paulo}
\title{A impossibilidade no direito civil brasileiro}
\begin{document}
\onehalfspacing

O problema geral da impossibilidade no direito civil deve ser dividido em duas frentes: a originária e a sucessiva.

A distinção tem por fundamento o momento em que ocorre a impossibilidade. Como ensina \footcite{AGUIARJUNIOR2004}, a norma nao visa a modificar o jurídico. \footcite{COUTOESILVA2009}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sure you will get better answers than mine, but since it is night in the US, this is the worst time to ask a question (not many people online to help). If you have a deadline, you can use my solution below for now.

Answer (score 3):

What you are talking about is the standard behaviour of the authortitle citing option of biblatex, that you have to choose in the preamble : `\usepackage[citestyle=authortitle-ibid,...]{biblatex}`. It means that you don't have a verbose citation style anymore. 
Of course, the capitalization of the first letter of the title depends on whether or not you put one in your reference database.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But i need Publisher; Edition; Place of publication and year to appear in the footnote as well. Is it possible? Just like this: ALMEIDA COSTA, Mário Júlio de. Obrigações. 9ª ed. Coimbra: Almedina, 2010.

Comment: What I don't understand is that you should have already had the full citation with your previous verbose style... Or you could try the \footfullcite command instead, it will print the full bibliography entry.

Answer (score 1):

I get this by using the package `natbib` in the following way:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, pagebackref=page, citecolor=blue, menucolor=red}
\usepackage{hypernat}

\begin{document}

Body

\newpage
\bibliographystyle{econometrica}
\bibliography{mybib}

\end{document}
```

Which produces

[image]

Some of the references have all the words starting with an uppercase character, but I think this depends on how this was written in my .bib file. If it happens that it puts the first letter of every word in uppercase, you can always enclose the name of the article in `{}` to force it to be written exactly as it is.

Comment: Thanks Vivi. But i can have no name abbreviation. Just like this: ABREU, José de. O negócio jurídico e sua teoria geral. 2ª ed. São Paulo: Saraiva, 2009.